# Is the return value of Dictionary.Last() undefined?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Today I encountered the use of `Dictionary.Last()` in some code I was reading. To me this did not make sense, because a dictionary does not have an unambiguous notion of the 'last' element. Checking [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx) gave me the following information:

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

which makes it sound like the result of `Last()` is undefined as well, but the method does not actually 'return items in order', it **implies it returns an item based on an internal order**. I may be overthinking this, but there is a difference there.

Doing my own tests using the following code resulted in "Fifteen" consistently being returned every time the test was run.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dictionary.Add(10, "Ten");
        dictionary.Add(5, "Five");
        dictionary.Add(20, "Twenty");           
        dictionary.Add(2, "Two");
        dictionary.Add(15, "Fifteen");

        Console.WriteLine(dictionary.Last());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

So now I am wondering if it is safe to assume that Dictionary.Last() returns the last added value, or if the method should not be used because the documentation says that *the order in which items are returned* is undefined while not clearly stating the behavior of `Last()`?

Comment: It's undefined for a dictionary, so don't use it and expect to get the last value added every time. It could change with different implementations (or it could change even with the current implementation after you've added a load of items to the dictionary).

Comment: Dictionary.Last exists solely because `Dictionary<K,V>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`. Thus, Dictionary.Last returns *the last element that would be returned when foreach-ing through the dictionary*.

Comment: The old non-generic type `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary` works more or less the way you ask for. The "last" entry is the one added last (however, you can use `.Insert` method to insert an entry in the middle, so in that case it will not be "last"). In your example that would be the one with `15`. This is different from `SortedList<,>` and `SortedDictionary<,>` for which the "last" entry is guaranteed to be the entry with the greatest key, in your example the one with `20`.

Comment: I'm not actually looking for a way to get a 'last' value though, I encountered code that used Dictionary.Last, which confused me. I would expect MSDN to 'override' the description for Dictionary.Last to explicitly remark that is has an undefined return value, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assumption that `Dictionary.Last()` always returns the last item added can easily be shown to fail, as follows:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Guid, Guid>();
Guid a = Guid.Empty, b = a, c = a, d = a;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    dict.Add(guid, guid);

    if (dict.Last().Key != guid)
        Console.WriteLine("Failed at iteration " + i);

    if (d != Guid.Empty)
        dict.Remove(d);

    d = c;
    c = b;
    b = a;
    a = guid;
}
```

**Therefore the return value of `Enumerable.Last()` used with a `Dictionary` is undefined.**

(For the current implementation of `Dictionary`, it looks like as soon as you remove an item, then `Last()` no longer returns the most recently added item.)

Answer (score 1):

*"I am wondering if it is safe to assume that Dictionary.Last() returns the last added value"*

No.

> **The order in which the items are returned is undefined**

They may be in the order you require *now* but undefined behavior is subject to change at any time as the internal implementation changes.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer to the question be YES? OP asks _is safe to assume_ (that is not - answer is NO) OR _the method should not be used_ (that answer is YES) so NO OR YES (correct me if I'm wrong) should be YES, right?

Comment: same as @Verarind `Last` is undefined by extension of the undefined ordering

Comment: As I stated, I don't feel that the 'order of returning items' is the same as 'having no defined/predictable internal order', but as I thought I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

The order itself is defined by the internals of `Dictionary`. Thus it seems *deterministic* as from the current implementation and returns the same order for the same input - in your case `Fifteen` will allways be the last item. However as the actual order relies on the internal implementation (probably on the hashcode of the keys) you should not rely on this order as it is unlikely to be what you´re expecting.

In particular the order is an implementation-detail. If you rely on this you´d get problems when Microsoft desides to change the internal code (not the API).

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation stating that the order is **deterministic**. There is nothing preventing a (silly) implementation to shuffle the results before giving them